# How to install OSGi bundle in program distribution

Tags: java, osgi

I have an application that I am converting to OSGi, and there are a couple of
bundles that are required (for now). These are jars that are included in the
program distribution. What is the best way to install these? I was looking
at using a classpath:xxx.jar, but is there a better way to do this?

thanks,
Lance

Comment: Which server are you using? Felix? Equinox? Knopperfish? It depends.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want an easy way to start up your application, without having to install all bundles from the console at every startup. If that is your current problem, you can take a look at

- http://paxrunner.ops4j.org/space/Pax+Runner , which eases the launching of the framework and deploying the bundles into it, or
- http://njbartlett.name/bndtools.html , an excellent Eclipse plugin that helps you during development.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that could be satisfying is to create a **feature** containing all your bundles. See for a hint [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/fossesi/archive/2010/09/16/some-results-converting-large-standard-java-app-set-osgi-bundles-bet). A feature is a package of bundles and it allows you to install a bunch of bundles with one command.